# Need to make a calculation based on multiple lookup results on another Excel sheet

Tags: excel, excel-2007, excel-formula

Need to try and get a result based on possible 3 lookups in Excel.
I have a price for a certain size hire vehicle and need to check to see if I want to add in a supplement or not based on entry into a cell in another sheet.

I have a sheet called Keys that has the criteria I base my calculations on and a second sheet I have the rates loaded for all the vehicle sizes available, cars to coaches.  I would like to calculate the supplement for customers of the move to a larger vehicle or even a reduction dependent on what I choose.

Keys data is:

```
Vehicle Sizes                               

Range    # Seats Rate    Column    Supplement    Range to work on

1        4               R         N    
2        7               S         Y             1
3        16              T         N    
4        24              U         Y             5
5        29              V         N    
6        35              W         N    
7        45              X         N
```

So for example if the I have chosen to calculate the supplement on the 7 seater then I want to calculate the difference between the 7 seater and 4 seater and that is my supplement.  I have also chosen to calculate the reduction between the 29 and 24 seater vehicles.

Am trying to figure out how to combine multiple IF and LOOKUP, if they are correct or not.

So basically IF I have a Y in the supplement column on Keys then calculate the difference in the rates based on the Rate Column based on the Range to work on.

Any suggestions or help appreciated

Sorry think I forgot about the actual rates.  They are stored on another sheet as per below.  the charges are per service, like an airport transfer etc., they are in VN Dong so thats why they are in the 100,000 + range.

R       S       T       U       V       W       X 
Rate with Surcharge
4   7   16  24  29  35  45
340000  373000  394000  735000  780000  1050000 1210000

I have tried to tweak the answer from pnuts but getting a bit lost, note sure if I need the MATCH in the formula of not.

Comment: Please explain your calc to get the `1` and the `5`.

Comment: You have put a `Y` in column `Supplement` for row numbered 4 when you're calculating a _reduction_?

Comment: @pnuts I'm not sure I'm following you. I mean, when there's a `Y` in the column `Supplement`, I'm expecting to have to calculate a supplement, and as such, compare 24 with the one before it; the 16 seater... or am I missing the purpose of the Rate Column?

Comment: The supplement could be an upgrade to a bigger vehicle of a reduction to a smaller vehicle.  The system being used to cost the service defaults to a price depending on the number of people but they could choose to have a different size vehicle thus the supp or reduction, not all vehicle sizes can be changed, in this case only two are offered, from 4 seater to 7 seater or down from 29 to 24.  different suppliers have different sizes and i want to be able to select which will be applied depending on location etc

Answer (score 1):

I doubt this will suit but it may help to clarify your requirements:

=IF($D2="N","",INDEX(Sheet2!$Q$2:$X$4,MATCH(F$1,Sheet2!$Q$2:$Q$4,0),CODE($C2)-80)-INDEX(Sheet2!$Q$2:$X$4,MATCH(F$1,Sheet2!$Q$2:$Q$4,0),CODE($C2)+$E2-$A1-81))

in F2 copied across and down to suit.

[image]

Comment: pnuts, this looks like close to what I need but have added din a bit more to the question about the rates. Am not sure if I need the MATCH statement as tried to change to have it but dont have it right.